# Screen stretch / compress for HDMI monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I adjust display size, not resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100074/how-do-i-adjust-display-size-not-resolution)

I have an HDMI external monitor.  When I connect it,  about 28 pixels are lost past the edges of the screen.  There is no option to stretch / compress  the screen in HDMI input mode.

Any options short of creating a custom screen resolution ... ?  Thanks!